# SQL SERVER: sumar campos con id similares

Tags: sql-server

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

### Tabla animales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Nota_servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito generar como resultado es mostrar el nombre del animal y cantidad de servicios que ha recibido cada animal, siempre y cuando hayan recibido 3 o mas servicios.
El codigo que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
select nombre, sum(Nota_servicio.cantidad) from animales inner join Nota_servicio on animales.id_animal=Nota_servicio.Id_animal where cantidad>=3 group by nombre
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para filtrar los resultados por un campo en el que has utilizado una función de agregación debes utilizar la clausula `having` y no la clausula `where`.

También recomiendo incluir el `id` del animal como parte de los campos de agrupación, por si hay dos animales que se llaman igual, pero en realidad son distintos, cosa que es bastante probable en la vida real.

```
select   animales.id_animal
       , animales.nombre
       , sum(Nota_servicio.cantidad) TotalServicios
  from animales 
       inner join Nota_servicio on animales.id_animal = Nota_servicio.Id_animal 
 group by animales.id_animal
        , animales.nombre
having sum(Nota_servicio.cantidad) >= 3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, resolvió por completo mi duda. Saludos!